# Visual Studio git commit date format

Tags: git, date, visual-studio-2022

I am using Visual Studio 2022 with its built-in git integration. My computer's locale/region/etc. is set to Australian, meaning the date is in the format of "day/month/year".

However the date of commits in VS's git window is in the US format of "month/day/year".

How can I change the format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which *Visual Studio 2022* version do you have? In the latest version (17.0, Decembre 2021) the problem should be resolved according to [this issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/git-repository-window-uses-wrong-date-format-regre/1556910).

So update/downloading just the latest version and you problem is fixed.
Here you can [downloading](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/) the latest version.

Comment: This doesn't work. My git history view in Visual Studio Code is still in the weird USA format

Comment: @Richard This is about visual studio, and not visual studio code...